# jq display nodes in one line

Tags: json, bash, jq

So I have this:

```
jq -r '.letters[0].secondary_letters[0] | "\(.name)"' letters.json
```

which outputs:

```
a
aa
```

I'd like them to be: a, aa

The json looks like:

```
  "secondary_letters": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "a"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "aa"
    }
```

There might be more so the jq command should be able to extract as many as sub nodes needed.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the input has been corrected so it is valid JSON,

```
jq -r '.secondary_letters | map(.name) | join(", ")'
```

produces

```
a, aa
```

The same filter also satisfies the generality requirement.

Answer (score 0):

do you want like this : ?

```
jq -r '.secondary_letters | map(.name)' letters.json
==> ["a" , "aa"]
```

If you need more attributes, .i.e: id:

```
jq -r '.secondary_letters | map(.name, .id)' letters.json
==> ["a" , 1, "aa", 2]
```

Comment: Thanks, yet  jq -r -c '.letters[0].secondary_letters[0] | map(.name)' letters.json did the trick :-)

Answer (score 0):

Simple ***jq*** approach:

```
jq -r '[.secondary_letters[].name] | join(", ")' letters.json
```

The output:

```
a, aa
```